# How to Select unique values from a table and select only timestamps where the time between each entry is higher then 10 seconds

Tags: sqlite

I have the following history table:

```
id, time, timestamp, mode
    1   18.03.2019 13:55:55 1552913755  
    2   26.03.2019 15:46:47 1553611607  Tool start
    3   26.03.2019 15:46:51 1553611611  Tool start
    4   26.03.2019 15:47:32 1553611652  Tool start
    5   26.03.2019 17:19:53 1553617193  Tool start
    6   26.03.2019 17:20:54 1553617254  Suspend
    7   26.03.2019 17:20:54 1553617254  Suspend
    8   26.03.2019 17:20:54 1553617254  Suspend
    9   26.03.2019 17:20:55 1553617255  Suspend
    10  27.03.2019 07:26:28 1553667988  Suspend
    11  27.03.2019 07:26:29 1553667989  Suspend
    12  27.03.2019 07:26:29 1553667989  Suspend
    13  27.03.2019 07:26:29 1553667989  Suspend
    14  27.03.2019 08:09:00 1553670540  Resume
    15  27.03.2019 08:09:10 1553670550  Resume
    16  27.03.2019 08:09:10 1553670550  Resume
    17  27.03.2019 08:09:10 1553670550  Resume
    18  27.03.2019 08:09:33 1553670573  Tool start
    19  27.03.2019 08:27:41 1553671661  Tool start
    20  27.03.2019 08:30:21 1553671821  Tool start
    21  27.03.2019 08:30:25 1553671825  Tool start
    22  27.03.2019 08:31:12 1553671872  Tool start
```

Now, I want to read only unique entries and in addition only values where the timestamp is > 10 minutes between each row.
The idea is to see only one "Suspend" and "Resume" entry.
It could happen that after 15 minutes another entry with Suspend should be displayed.

This query will show me the unique values:

```
SELECT * FROM history GROUP by timestamp
```

But I am not able to show only one Suspend and Resume in a range of 15 minutes.

Comment: What is your expected result for this data?

Comment: The idea is to have unique entries. Also my app is wrinting multible times of Suspend and Resume into the table. This I want to remove from this table.